# How to refer to class using variable

Tags: javascript

If I have this object:

```
var myclass = {

  foo: {
    bar: function(var) {}
  },
  some: {
    bar: function(var) {}
  }
}
```

and I want to call the bar function depending on a variable that defines the parent level of the object like this:

```
var part = "some";
myclass.part.bar(var);
```

How can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by 'parent level'? Do you mean the *context* (aka `this` in the function)?

Comment: I mean the "foo" or the "some"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using array access notation:

```
myclass[part].bar(var);
```

JavaScript objects are like associative arrays, and you can use a property name to either set or get the property's value, you can even create new properties with this syntax.

For example:

```
var obj = { a : 1 };
console.log(obj["a"]); // 1
obj["b"] = 2; // this creates a property called b and assigns 2 as the value
console.log(obj["b"]); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to a function as a variable, which is a little cleaner than a string.

```
var func = myclass.foo.bar;//or myclass.some.bar
...
func.call(myclass, var);
```

Or keep a reference to the part:

```
var part = myclass.foo;//or myclass.some
part.bar.call(myclass, var);
```